# Is it possible to determine the (pixel-)width of text-strings bevore SVGs are created with scripts

Tags: perl, winapi, text, svg

I am about the create a bunch of SVG graphics with (probabably) a perl script. These SVG graphics will contain text blocks. Since I want to "connect" such text blocks (of varying widths) with lines I'd like to know what width a text will be so that I can draw the connecting lines' length accordingly.

I have seen in [SVG get text element width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636842/svg-text-element-width) that it could be possible with java script. But that's probably not what I am after since I don't intend to host the SVG in a browser.

So, I thought that maybe there's a way to find out the desired width at the script's runtime. If someone can point me to a solution (also outside the realm of perl but on windows), I'd be very gratefu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did that exactly that about a year ago using PDF::API2 and advancewidth function:  https://metacpan.org/module/PDF::API2::Content#width-txt-advancewidth-string-text_state-

Note that you need to correlate DPI of PDF and SVG: they may be different (I actually did that just dividing values by 1.25, you can be better).

PDF::API2 gives you very accurate values that works for Inkscape (in my case) well.