# How to create a horizontal legend with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying to create a horizontal legend for my graph using d3.js. I've struggled to get the x-axis spacing correct with dynamic labels.

The problem is that the labels are not of a consistent width, here's a [full example](http://bl.ocks.org/4336932) and this is my function to calculate the x position:

```
function legendXPosition(data, position, avgFontWidth){
    if(position == 0){
        return 0;
    } else {
        var xPostiion = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < position; i++){
            xPostiion += (data[i].length * avgFontWidth);
        }
        return xPostiion;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve this?

Comment: It may help to specify what is 'incorrect' about your spacing. They have a bit of extra padding in my view. Is that what you are trying to get rid of? Or are you looking for alternate renderings?

Comment: Sorry the length of the label effects the spacing of the next Item in the label e.g. "adasdasd" creates a disproportionate space to the next item compared to "asd". In other words my x positioning function doesn't seem to be correctly accounting for the size of the label, leaving spacing between the labels which seems to be related to the number of characters in the label.

Comment: I have given my answer to this question here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52256345/9532759

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest referencing this question: [SVG get text element width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636842/svg-text-element-width)

Render the first legend entry as you already are. Store this entry, or assign ids such that you can look them up through selection.

When rendering subsequent entries, get the previous 'text' element and x offset. Compute the new legend entry offset using the exact width of the previous text element

```
var myNewXOffset = myPreviousXOffset + myPreviousText.getBBox().width
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code to get the following result
[image]
The reason your labels are not of a consistent width is due to two factors. Both of them are related to your function to calculate the x position:

1. the avgFontWidth parameter

It should be smaller. You assigned it the value of `15` in your [example](http://bl.ocks.org/martinffx/4336932), but the actual averageFontWidth is way smaller than `15`, it was between `5` to `7`. The extra space between your legend labels come from this inaccurate value of average font width.

Your `avgFontWidth` is just an average. In reality, fonts width change.For example, the `r` in the picture below is way narrower than the `P`.
[image]
Thus the five letter word `rrrrr` can be way shorter than `PPPPP` when the font family is set in some way. In conclusion, you shall not use `avgFontWidth`. You should use  **[SVG get text element width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636842/svg-get-text-element-width)** as **cmonkey** suggests

2. the logic of `xPostiion += (data[i].length * avgFontWidth)`
   The above formula intends to calculate the length of the text, but the width of the label shall also be added, `xPostiion` should be

`xPostiion += (data[i].length * avgFontWidth) + widthOftheLabel`

The modified code:

```js
function drawlinegraph(data, startDateString, endDateString, maxValue, minValue, colour,
  divID, labels) {
  var m = {
      top: 60,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 35,
      left: 80
    },
    w = 770 - m.left - m.right,
    h = 180 - m.top - m.bottom,
    dateFormat = "%Y-%m-%d";

  labels = ["ada", "adas", "asdasdasd", "sd"];

  var parseDate = d3.time.format(dateFormat).parse;

  var startDate = parseDate(startDateString);
  var endDate = parseDate(endDateString);

  // Define the x scale
  var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([startDate, endDate])
    .range([0, w]);

  // Format x-axis labels
  x.tickFormat(d3.time.format(dateFormat));

  // Define the y scale
  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([minValue, maxValue])
    .range([h, 0]);

  var graph = d3.select(divID).append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w + m.right + m.left)
    .attr("height", h + m.top + m.bottom)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m.left + "," + m.top + ")");

  // create x-axis
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(4)
    .tickSize(-h)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y/%m"));

  // Add the x-axis.
  graph.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  // Overide the default behaviour of d3 axis labels
  d3.selectAll(".x.axis g text")[0].forEach(function(e) {
    e.attributes[0].value = 8; // y
  });

  // create y-axis
  var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(12)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSize(-w);

  // Add the y-axis to the left
  graph.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(yAxisLeft);

  var i = 0;
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    value.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
      });
    graph.append("path")
      .datum(value)
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("stroke", colour[i]);
    i++;
  });

  var legend = graph.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-5,' + (h + 35) + ')');


  legend.selectAll('rect')
    .data(labels)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      var xPost = legendXPosition(labels, i, 6);
      return xPost;
    })
    .attr("y", -6)
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      var color = colour[i];
      return color;
    });

  legend.selectAll('text')
    .data(labels)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      var xPost = legendXPositionText(labels, i, 22, 6);
      return xPost;
    })
    .attr("y", -1)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });
};

function legendXPositionText(data, position, textOffset, avgFontWidth) {
  return legendXPosition(data, position, avgFontWidth) + textOffset;
}

function legendXPosition(data, position, avgFontWidth) {
  if (position == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    var xPostiion = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < position; i++) {
      xPostiion += (data[i].length * avgFontWidth + 40);
    }
    return xPostiion;
  }
}

var benchmark_line_graph_colours = ["#524364", "#937ab1", "#ab5b02", "#faa757"],
  benchmark_line_graph_data = {
    "Beassa ALBI TR ZAR": [{
      "date": "2012-08-31",
      "value": 101.1
    }, {
      "date": "2012-09-28",
      "value": 101.89
    }, {
      "date": "2012-10-31",
      "value": 101.09
    }],
    "FTSE/JSE All Share TR ZAR": [{
      "date": "2012-08-31",
      "value": 99.72
    }, {
      "date": "2012-09-28",
      "value": 101.24
    }, {
      "date": "2012-10-31",
      "value": 105.29
    }],
    "STeFI Composite ZAR": [{
      "date": "2012-08-31",
      "value": 100.23
    }, {
      "date": "2012-09-28",
      "value": 100.52
    }, {
      "date": "2012-10-31",
      "value": 100.77
    }],
    "portfolio": [{
      "date": "2012-08-31",
      "value": 101.55
    }, {
      "date": "2012-09-28",
      "value": 101.15
    }, {
      "date": "2012-10-31",
      "value": 102.08
    }]
  };
drawlinegraph(benchmark_line_graph_data,
  "2012-08-31",
  "2012-10-31",
  105.84700000000001,
  99.163, benchmark_line_graph_colours,
  "body");
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.x.axis text {
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-anchor: "right";
}
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.y.axis line,
.y.axis path {
  stroke-dasharray: 2, 2;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
```