# Get width of d3.js SVG text element after it's created

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to get the widths of a bunch of `text` elements I have created with d3.js

This is how I'm creating them:

```
var nodesText = svg.selectAll("text")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("text")
           .text(function(d) {
                return d.name;
           })
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return i * (w / dataset.length);
           })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
                return 45;
          });
```

I'm then using the width to create `rectangles` the same size as the `text`'s boxes

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return i * (w / dataset.length);
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return 25;
            })
            .attr("width", function(d, i) {
              //To Do: find width of each text element, after it has been generated
              var textWidth = svg.selectAll("text")
                  .each(function () {
                      return d3.select(this.getComputedTextLength());
                  });
                console.log(textWidth);
                return textWidth;
            })
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return 30;
            })
```

I tried using the Bbox method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636842/svg-text-element-width) but I don't really understand it. I think selecting the actual element is where I'm going wrong really.

Answer (score 15):

I would make the length part of the original data:

```
var nodesText = svg.selectAll("text")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
       })
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length);
       })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
            return 45;
      })
      .each(function(d) {
        d.width = this.getBBox().width;
      });
```

and then later

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; });
```

Comment: what is the 'w' in (w / dataset.length)? I looked at [svg text](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElement) and [d3 text](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#text) and cannot find what 'w' is

Comment: The total width you set for the text.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()`

Example:

```
.style('top', function (d) {
     var currElemHeight = this.getBoundingClientRect().height;
}
```

edit: seems like its more appropriate for HTML elements. for SVG elements you can use *getBBbox()* instead.

Answer (score 0):

`d3.selectAll` returns a **selection**. You can get each of the **elements** by navigating through the array in the `_groups` property. When you are determining the width of a rectangle, you can use its index to get the corresponding text element:

```
.attr('width', function (d, i) {
    var textSelection = d3.selectAll('text');
    return textSelection._groups[0][i].getComputedTextLength();
});
```

The `_groups` property of d3's selection has a list of nodes at `[0]`. This list contains all of the selected **elements**, which you can access by index. It's important that you get the SVG *element* so that you can use the `getComputedTextLength` method.

You may also want to consider creating the `rect` elements first, then the `text` elements, and then going back to the rectangles to edit the `width` attribute, so that the `text` elements are on top of the rectangles (in case you want to fill the rectangles with color).

**Update:**

It's typically preferred that you don't access `_groups`, though, so a safer way to get the matching text element's width would be:

```
.attr('width', function (d, i) {
    return d3.selectAll('text').filter(function (d, j) { return i === j; })
        .node().getComputedTextLength(); 
});
```

Using `node` safely retrieves the element, and filter will find the text element which matches index.