# document.querySelector(...).offsetWidth returns null in Firefox

Tags: javascript, svg, offsetwidth

I use the following code in my javascript (coffeescript) file:

```
myVar = document.querySelector('SVG > a:nth-child(2) > text').offsetWidth
```

In google chrome this returns the width of a the text element which is nested inside an a (anchor) element which is nested inside an svg element, as is expected. In Firefox this returns a NULL. I thought that perhaps my selector syntax wasn't up to Mozilla's standards so I played around with that as well, but even if I could select the DOM element correctly (as outputted by the console) I was unable to retrieve any property offsetWidth; it would always come back as undefined.

Now, in case it matters, my SVG object in injected into my page dynamically by some Javascript. It's placed directly into the body of a div and enclosed in `<svg>` and `</svg>` tags.

What gives? How can I ascertain the width of these elements?

Thanks!

Comment: Good, offsetWidth is only valid for html elements so Firefox is behaving perfectly correctly per http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-htmlelement-interface

Answer (score 3):

[NickFitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16782/nickfitz)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637014/5059145) at  is what you need.

He offers to use SVG's standart function [`getBBox()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable).

`myVar = document.querySelector (...).getBBox ().width`